# Add option to show all hot network questions in addition to 15, 30 and 50

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

[Hot Network Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/) is set up to show links to popular questions divided into pages. Pages are perfect for cases where their contents don't change between flipping, like posts sorted by "newest". But if you've been on the internet and browsed sites like reddit with posts sorted by current popularity (hotness, bestness), you know how you still get to see posts you've just seen on the previous page if you're not flipping fast enough (too fast). Same happens here. It's frustrating and there's an easy fix.

You've already given us the option to get 50 posts per page, making it just 2 pages. Would it be much more load on the server to allow people to see all 100 hottest posts on one page? Pretty please?

Comment: Well, there's no list on SE showing 100 questions, or 100 items.

Comment: There's also no other Hot Questions list like per-site. Why must you find arguments to deny this unique feature for a unique page :I